# How do I modify a python array of strings to strip any alphanumerics, convert to float, and then store the float in the same array?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a 2-D array that when printed row by row looks like this:

```
labStorageArray = []

for line in labStorageShort.splitlines():
  labStorageArray.append(line.strip().split(' '));

for row in labStorageArray:
        print row

['random1', '4.75M']
['random2', '4.8G']
```

I want to convert the second element of each row (which is obviously storage sizes), to a float so that I can convert all of the values to TB.  Is there an easy way to do this and keep the data in the same array to later be printed?

Comment: Don't you need to parse the text to separate `M` from `G`?

Comment: Yes.  But that part seems easy using a if/else loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from string import ascii_letters

s='4.75M'
print(float(s.rstrip(ascii_letters))
4.75
```

If there is only and always a single end character to remove:

```
print(float(s[:-1])))
4.75
```

Presuming the float is always last element:

```
for line in labStorageShort.splitlines():
    spl = line.rstrip().split()
    letter, flt = spl[-1][-1], float(spl[-1][:-1])  # if there are possibly nums without a letter use rstrip   
     # do calculation here if preferable 
     # flt = flt / 1024 if letter == "G" else flt 
    labStorageArray.append(spl[0],flt)
```

Comment: This doesn't really accomplish the task for the entire array, changing the data in the array, does it?

Comment: just iterate over the array, the logic is exactly the same

Comment: no worries, if you only have two elements use `labStorageArray.append([spl[0],float(spl[1][:-1]))`

Comment: @JonathanDeMasi, how can it be "best" to **ignore** the suffix, e.g M vs G?!  Seems pretty crucial...

Comment: Pretty simple to throw in the condition `if "G" in row[1]: print(float(s.rstrip(ascii_letters)))/(1024))

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the number *always* ends in `M` or `G`; if there's a possibility of no suffix at all, the logic gets just a little more involved.

```
multiplier = {'M': 1048576, 'G': 1073741824}  # or 1000000 and 1000000000, your choice
for row in labStorageArray:
    number, suffix = row[1][:-1], row[1][-1]
    number = float(number) * multiplier[suffix]
    row[1] = number
```

Result:

```
[['random1', 4980736.0], ['random2', 5153960755.2]]
```